# Центрирование логотипа относительно блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

возможно это легкая задача, но не могу понять как это решить. Переписываю дизайн со своего же сайта. Шапка сайта сделана с помощью flex, хочу центрировать логотип относительно этой шапки, но логотип центрируется относительно экрана:

[Мой код сейчас](https://codepen.io/kolyageshko/pen/KKqePgx)

[Мой сайт, на котором работает все корректно](https://citadelcult.com/)

```
.absolute-center {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

это и правда мой сайт, я не пытаюсь скопировать чужой дизайн, могу подтвердить домен.

Comment: существует много способов центрирования элементов по горизонтали и вертикали. раз у вас flexbox, то логично им воспользоваться. уберите абсолютное позиционирование, а далее делайте [настройку выравнивания отдельного элемента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8_align-self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.absolute-center {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 35px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-35px);
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```